# pygraphviz multiple edges from the same node aren't working on Mac OS X

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygraphviz

I installed dependencies like this.

```
brew install python
brew install graphviz
pip3 install --user --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/include/" --install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/lib/" pygraphviz
```

After that I tried a simple script (copy-pasted from somewhere in the internet). Multiple edges simply are not working! I set `strict=False`, but it didn't help.

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G=pgv.AGraph(strict=False)
G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.layout()
G.add_edge('a','b','first')
G.add_edge('a','b','second')
sorted(G.edges(keys=True)) 
G.draw('file.png')
```

Everytime I execute this script, what I got is this.

[image: result]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually for me your code works: i have two edges between `a` and `b`. i executed it on my mac and the only difference in the installation of pygraphviz is that i installed the python lib via anaconda navigator. i got version 1.3.

Comment: It sounds like issue [#162](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/162)

Comment: Try installing an older version of graphviz (the native one not the pip), specifically v 2.38

Comment: @brennan `brew install graphviz --HEAD` fixed everything. Please, post an answer, so I can approve it.

Comment: @Inline thanks, but you should! I didn't offer a solution :P What does `brew info graphviz` say your version is now? https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/graphviz PS It looks like the repo on Github is just a mirror, with active dev on Gitlab. https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz

Comment: @brennan `graphviz: stable 2.40.1 (bottled), HEAD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`brew install graphviz --HEAD` which installs version `graphviz: stable 2.40.1 (bottled), HEAD` resolves problem for me.

Other have reported that this issue is bug [#162](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/162), but it seems to be different problem.